# javascript for a link inside php not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a link in php and using javascript I was trying it to make background image from "read.png" to "read.png_light" when mouse is over. Any idea how to make it work?

```
<?php
echo "<a href='messages.php?hash=$hash'>";                  
?>

<onmouseover="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read_light.png';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read.png';">       

<img src="img/read.png" id="mage"/>

<?php               
echo"</a>";
?>
```

Comment: What is this `<onmouseover="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read_light.png';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read.png';">`?

Comment: since when has HTML had `<onmouseover>` tags?

Comment: is use this before and worked for a similar link that is was not including a php echo:        <a href="start_post_job.php"
       onmouseover="document.getElementById('mage1').src='img/post_job_light.png';"
       onmouseout="document.getElementById('mage1').src='img/post_job.png';">  
       <img src="img/post_job.png" id="mage1"/></a>

Comment: @Marc B - It is not a <onmouseover> tag, it is an anonymous tag with onmouseover attr. Straight from HTML7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onmouseover is not a tag, but an **event attribute**! [Here are some info](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onmouseover)

Hence, it must be put inside an element tag.

- In the example provided in your question, onmouseover/onmouseout are
  written like if they're a tag: `<onmouseover>`. That's why it doesn't work.
- In the example provided in your first comment, onmouseover was inside
  an anchor tag, like `<a onmouseover....></a>`. That's why it worked.

Have you tried:

```
//onmouseover and onmouseout are inside the <img> tag
<?php
echo "<a href='messages.php?hash=$hash'>";                  
?>

<img src="img/read.png" id="mage" 
onmouseover="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read_light.png';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read.png';" />       

<?php               
echo"</a>";
?>
```

OR

```
//onmouseover and onmouseout are inside the <a> tag
<?php
echo "<a href='messages.php?hash=$hash' ";                  
?>
onmouseover="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read_light.png';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('mage').src='img/read.png';" 

<?php echo ">"; ?>


<img src="img/read.png" id="mage" />       

<?php               
echo"</a>";
?>
```

?

Comment: Thanks looks that working. The only problem is that "read.png" is the image that displayed near to each message, in my message system that I made it in php. Messages are displayed through a while loop. So each message displayed has this image next to it. The problem now is that if I have for example 3 new messages and user place mouse over 1 messages image read.png changes to read_light.png successfull. But if places mouse over 2 or 3 messages it changes the image to first message.

Comment: use EventListener! And please do not link to w3scho...

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Comment: The CSS way below, will only change the image for the current image being rolled-over, OR you will have to make all of your ids for each img tags unique (they should be anyway)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to your code like this:

```
<script>
   var read = 'img/read.png';
   var read_light = img/read_light.png;
</script>
<?php
     echo "<a href='messages.php?hash=$hash' onmouseover='document.getElementById('mage').src=read_light;' onmouseout='document.getElementById('mage').src=read;'>
?>

<img src="img/read.png" id="mage"/>

<?php               
     echo"</a>";
?>
```

---

A nicer way to do it using CSS would be like this:

Your generated html:

```
<a href='messages.php?hash=$hash' class="swap">                  
    <span id="mage">Text</span>
</a>
```

Then attach this CSS to your HTML:

```
a #mage {
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    background-image:url('img/read.png'); 
}

 a #mage:hover { 
     background-image:url(img/read_light.png); 
}
```

Comment: pleasure, glad you got some good answers, everyone needs to start somewhere.